# javah.exe- Entry Point Not Found

Tags: java, android-ndk

I tried the sample project for NDK given in the link:
      http://stevethai.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/android-helloworld-with-native-code-tutorial/

But while running the command "javah com.hello.LibC" it shows the following error:

The procedure entry poin JLI_ExactVersionId could not be located in the dynamic link     library jli.dll

I dont know what is the problem. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem. 
When that error message pop up I had tried to analyze what process show it. I used TaskInfo tool, but you perhaps could also use SysInternals Process Exporer. Or SpyXX tool from Microsoft.

While I was searched I found that it was started wrong version of JAR.EXE - the older version which were copied to C:\utils directory long time ago.
So, I removed (renamed) wrong JAR.EXE and started Cordova tool again, this time all was working fine, so - no more errors.

Thus, I think that error happened because of using wrong/older versions of some Java-specific tools which could be available in %PATH%. Check your %PATH% and try to fix it.